# Is it possible to bind a property to itself through a converter in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I need to change value of a property on a trigger, and I need to do it according to the existing value with some parameter. So, I've tried to use xaml like this:

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger ...>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                ConverterParameter=ParamValue}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And converter is simple:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object existingValue, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //change the brush
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But with such code existingValue parameter in MyConverter.Convert() is null.

So, is there a way to apply converter to a property using its own value? I can't pass it as ConverterParameter because that is used for another data needed by the converter.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to do this, it is just what `IValueConverters` *do*. `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, 
                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />` Your converter will now receive the original `Brush` via `existingValue`, and you can change it to something else in whatever way you want.

Comment: Unless I'm totally misunderstanding what you are asking.  If that's not what you are asking about, please clarify your question.

Comment: @BradleyUffner note that that parameter is normally just `value`, not `existingValue`.  @brainpusher renamed it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Indeed, I was just using the names from his existing code.

Comment: What is your trigger based on? If it's just some other property, I would recommend just binding to the BorderBrush normally and use an IValueConverter or IMultiValueConverter and pass in everything you need to calculate the brush color at any given time instead of using a trigger.